# Building a 'shadow stack' across threads when profiling the CLR

Tags: c++, .net, stack, profiling, clr

I am building a profiler, and am trying to replicate the call stack of the application being profiled.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384634(v=vs.90).aspx) on profiling the CLR recommends building a 'shadow' stack using the  Enter/Leave method callbacks (`SetEnterLeaveFunctionHooks`), rather than using the snapshot method.

Is there a way to associate these callbacks when they are part of the same call stack, but could potentially occur on different threads? (for example, when the application being profiled uses `Task.Run` or `async/await`).

Ideally, I would like to show the user a call stack that 'follows' async methods, so associating them by `ThreadId` is unreliable.

Comment: No, that's not simple.  The debugger can do it, I'm 87.23% sure that it uses [this helper method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882494.aspx).  Notable above all because it documents an internal method.  But the caveats it mentions do apply, a profiler is not a debugger and have to freeze the threads is going to hurt pretty badly.

Comment: @HansPassant That's helpful, thank you.